# alias a template function that has no parameter for more concise calling

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

How to alias a certain template function to make it called by using shorter syntax?

From ....

```
getSystem<SystemX>()->    //get semi-singleton instance of "SystemX"
```

... to something like this:-

```
getSystem<SystemX>->       or
getSystem(SystemX)->       or
{SystemX}->                or
SystemX=>                 (can I define new strange operator?)
```

At first, I don't think it is a problem at all, but after several months, I think there might be a more concise way (syntax) to call it. (I use it in 400+ location).

I believe it is possible by using the same trick as `std::is_enable_t<T>`=`std::is_enable<T>::value`. (?)

[**full code**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dfab1d801d104ed5)

## My poor workarounds

Besides making the name shorter e.g. `getSystem<SystemA>()->` to  `ss<A>()->` , here are my workarounds.

### Solution A

Instead of calling `getSystem<SystemA>()->`, I would call `SystemA::` instead.

**Disadvantage:**

- Every function of system now become static function.
- There can't be any 2 instance of the same system inside my program anymore.
- [Common disadvantage of singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-are-drawbacks-or-disadvantages-of-singleton-pattern/138012#138012) : Global variable, break single responsibility, etc.

### Solution B

By using macro, the result is exactly what I want :-

```
#define S(param) getSystem<param>()   
S(SystemA)->fa()
```

However, [macro has some disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305844/advantages-disadvantages-of-implementing-functions-as-macros-in-c/16306620#16306620).
I feel that this is not a place to use this type of hack.

Sorry, if it is too newbie, I am very new to C++.

Comment: So `getSystem<SystemA>()` is defined in the base class? Does it return a static object? What does it do? Typically when I need a child object to communicate with a parent, I use a reference or pointer of some kind.

Comment: @Dustin Goodson  Yes, it is defined in base class like `template<class T>T* getSystem(){...}`.  It returns non-static object i.e. instance of `new SystemA()`.  Such instances were injected by another top-level class since start of the game (it is a bit off-topic, so I will stop here).

Comment: What is so wrong in `getSystem<SystemX>()` vs `getSystem(SystemX)` does the pair of empty parentheses hurt so much? You could use template argument deduction but I doubt it would improve syntax.

Comment: @luk32  At first, I don't think it is, but after typing it several times, I believe I could be a little more productive and code would be more readable if there is an alias (just for this function).  Sorry if it sounds too newbie.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with typing getSystem<SystemA>(), unless you have 100s of such calls for only a few SystemX classes (which may indicate some logic issues in your function).  You could use aliases at the cpp. level to save some key strokes, something like using A=SystemA; etc.  Then you'd have something like getSystem<A>(),  etc...

Comment: @Michaël Roy  Thank for a workaround.  It would be handy in such highly-repetitive cases.  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
class SystemB : public SystemBase {
    inline auto getSystemA(void) { return getSystem<SystemA>(); }
    inline auto getSystemB(void) { return getSystem<SystemB>(); }
    void fb();
};
void SystemB::fb(){
    getSystemA()->fa();
}
```

Since you want to use the `SystemBase::getSystem` from the `SystemB` object, the function goes in the SystemB class.